# Sort Two Columns by Unique Values

Tags: excel-2010

I have two columns (A and B) with numbers. I need to sort by matching number from Col A and Col B, so that I can see which ones of them match.

Col A--Col B

2333--1222

2445--2333

2500--2400

2501--2445

..etc

I need it to look like this:

Col A--Col B

xxxx--1222

2333--2333

xxxx--2400

2445--2445

2500--xxxx

2501--xxxx

etc..

EDIT: I copied the values from Col B to Col A and sorted smallest to largest. This matches the values. Now I need to delete the ones that don't have duplicates. Ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you show us an example of what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/564176-how-to-match-values-in-one-column-to-values-in-another.html)

Use this formula in Column C all the way to the end of your data and then sort.

```
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,B:B,0)),A2,"")
```